# Can we add Pre-condition as a field in Test case in VSTS

Tags: azure-devops, testcase

While writing test cases in VSTS, there is a field called 'Precondition'. Is there a way that we can add Precondition in Test case template before each steps ?
Current test case template is: Steps, Action, Expected result and Attachments. Can we add Preconditions as a of the column for each steps?

Answer (score 0):

Currently, it is not supported to add custom column between "Steps" and "Action" as "Precondition" in Azure DevOps.

If you want to use custom fields to record prerequisites to show up in Test Case, you can vote for the suggestions below:

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/admins-ability-to-choose-fields-that-should-show-u/366029